# Как с помощью тг бота, запустить код telethon

Tags: python, aiogram, telethon

У меня есть простой тг бот, у него есть одна функция старт, с инлайн клавишей "Подключиться к аккаунту", после нажатия на эту клавишу я хочу, чтобы у меня запустился код регистрации аккаунта Telethon, но у меня возникли с этим проблемы:

Код бота:

```
bot = Bot(token=token)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot, storage=storage)




async def on_startup(_):
   await db.db_start()
   print('Бот успешно запущен')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
   await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выбери что хочешь")
   if message.from_user.id == int(admin_id):
       await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет админ)", reply_markup=main_admin)


@dp.message_handler(text='Подключиться к аккаунту')
async def all_message(message: types.Message):
   if message.from_user.id == int(admin_id):
       await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Подключаюсь")
       #тут должен запускаться код Telethon с подключением в тг аккаунт
```

Код Telethon:

````
api_hash = '7'


client = TelegramClient('my_session', api_id, api_hash)

input_message = ('blablabla')


async def send_message_to_channel(channel_username, message_text):
    try:
        entity = await client.get_entity(channel_username)

        await client.send_message(entity, message_text)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")


async def main():
    await client.start()

    channel_messages = {
        'https://t.me/canal': f'{input_message}',
        'https://t.me/canal': f'{input_message}',
        'https://t.me/canal': f'{input_message}',
    }

    while True:
        for channel_username, message_text in channel_messages.items():
            await send_message_to_channel(channel_username, message_text)

        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio

    asyncio.run(main()) ```
````